# gradle error "Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI"

Tags: gradle

I have defined two system properties in gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.buildDir=build
systemProp.cfgDir=build\\cfg
```

And I have the following task defined in build.gradle:

```
task clean(group:'clean',description:'clean the project') << {
    ant.sequential {
        delete(dir: System.properties.buildDir)
        mkdir(dir: System.properties.buildDir)
        delete(dir: System.properties.cfgDir)
        mkdir(dir: System.properties.cfgDir)
    }
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':clean'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: {dir=build}.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence path, e.g 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'
    - A String or CharSequence URI, e.g 'file:/usr/include'
    - A File instance.
    - A URI or URL instance.
```

But this equivalent block of code does not generate any error and works as expected:

```
task clean(group:'clean',description:'clean the project') << {
    ant.delete(dir: System.properties.buildDir)
    ant.mkdir(dir: System.properties.buildDir)
    ant.delete(dir: System.properties.cfgDir)
    ant.mkdir(dir: System.properties.cfgDir)
}
```

Is the error on the first syntax a bug in gradle, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by the fact that your Gradle build script delegates to an instance of the `Project` interface, which also has a method called `delete`, whose argument is evaluated by `Project.file()`. If you want to use the Ant task you'll have to qualify it with the `ant` prefix.